# Saving data from scanner to string multidimensional array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to save data such as name, surname, etc... from different clients, and then to have a possibility to choose one of them and view all his data.

I tried with multidimensional array (using loop), but its not working.

Here is the code I tried:

```
void objectsMaking(){
    TeleAddressData teleAddressData = new TeleAddressData();

    for(int i=0; i<teleAddressData.tableOfNames.length; i++){
        System.out.println(teleAddressData.tableOfNames[i]);

        String[] list = new String[howManyClients];
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        teleAddressData.tablicaDanych[howManyClients-1][i] = scanner1.nextLine();   
    }
```

I made an object of TeleAddressData class, because there is an array with names such as name, surname ect. So loop "for" takes those names.

> teleAddressData.tablicaDanych[howManyClients-1][i] = scanner1.nextLine();

this part should store scanner lines in certain array's cells but I think it is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have `String[][]` here, you should have some meaningful object (Client?) and have `Client[]`.

Beyond that it seems very odd as you are constantly making a new list, and then never assigning that new list into your main data set, and then assigning a value to a probably never initialized array.